# Coconut has saturated fats amounting to 150%. What does that mean physically ? How can fats be more than 100 percent?

Tags: percentages

[CLICK HERE to see the nutrient chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b43w3.png)
If I take 100 grams of coconut then how can I physically have fats in that which are 150% ?

Its physically understandable that coconut has 5% carbohydrates that is every 100 gm of coconut has 5 gm carbohydrate. But what's the physical meaning of coconut having 150% fats ? How many grams fats are there in 100 gm coconut ?

Comment: `150 %` of *what*?

Comment: If you are looking at nutritional amounts, these are often percentages *of your recommended daily intake*.

Comment: @dxiv `I think` if OP could answer your *emphatic* question, they wouldn't have the question in the first place.  `Wouldn't` you *agree*?

Comment: Its physically understandable that coconut has 5% carbohydrates that is every 100 gm of coconut has 5 gm carbohydrate. But what's the physical meaning of coconut having 150% fats ? How many grams fats are there in 100 gm coconut ?

Comment: @user46944 150%.

Comment: Where have you found this statistic?  dxiv is correct that as it stands we're missing information.

Comment: google as "coconut nutrients" and you will see percent break up of its nutrients on first page itself

Comment: @ComputerMaster Percentages are a relative ratio based on some reference number. Your `150 %` describes the ratio, but it makes no absolute sense unless you specify what the reference number is that you compare to. Sorry, voting to close as "*unintelligible*" until/unless you clarify that point.

Comment: @ComputerMaster P.S. Please lookup what `% Daily Value` is defined to mean in the link you just added, and that should answer your question.

Comment: @ComputerMaster It looks from your link/picture that the recommended amount of saturated fat a person should have each day is 20g.  Since the total amount of saturated fat in the coconut serving is 30g, which is 150% of 20 (since $30/20 = 1.5$), that means the **percent daily value** of saturated fat is 150%.  Percent daily value just tells you, in this case, how much you are getting from 30g of saturated fat as compared to how much you should get in a day.  If you consume 30g of saturated fat, you've consumed 150% of what you should have for that day.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're looking at the nutritional values.

If it says the coconut has 150% fats this does NOT mean that a coconut is 150% fat, rather the coconut contains 150% of your daily recommended intake of fats.

That is (this is probably not correct), if you are recommended to eat 50 g of fat every day, a coconut may contain 75 g of fat (150% of 50 g). HOWEVER, the coconut itself may weigh 500 g.

Just remember a percentage on a nutrition label always refers to percent of recommended daily values NOT a part of the actual food item. Therefore you can have 50% for fats, 50% for carbohydrates, as well as 50% for proteins, even though they add up to more than 100%.